# unable to stat ���]V '/var/lib/dpkg/info/systemd.postinst': Structure needs cleaning

Tags: 18.04, apt, package-management, upgrade, dpkg

System info: 18.04.1-Ubuntu

Somehow my apt got corrupted. Getting two different error messages when I try to update nodejs:

```
01:~$ sudo apt upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  linux-azure-headers-5.0.0-1031 linux-azure-headers-5.0.0-1032 linux-headers-5.0.0-1031-azure linux-headers-5.0.0-1032-azure linux-image-5.0.0-1031-azure linux-image-5.0.0-1032-azure
  linux-modules-5.0.0-1031-azure linux-modules-5.0.0-1032-azure
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
The following packages will be upgraded:
  nodejs
1 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/24.3 MB of archives.
After this operation, 48.1 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] 
(Reading database ... 181911 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../nodejs_13.14.0-1nodesource1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking nodejs (13.14.0-1nodesource1) over (13.13.0-1nodesource1) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/nodejs_13.14.0-1nodesource1_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 unable to stat './usr/share/doc/node' (which I was about to install): Structure needs cleaning
dpkg-deb: error: paste subprocess was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/nodejs_13.14.0-1nodesource1_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

and

```
01:~$ sudo dpkg --configure -a
Setting up systemd (237-3ubuntu10.39) ...
dpkg: error processing package systemd (--configure):
 unable to stat ���]V '/var/lib/dpkg/info/systemd.postinst': Structure needs cleaning
Errors were encountered while processing:
 systemd
```

any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: try `sudo apt clean`.